# Is it Possible to embed a HTA application in a Webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, client-side, hta

Can we embed a HTA application in a Webpage to run at client system. 
Please someone let me know.

Comment: Havr you read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536495%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Could you provide a context where you would embed a HTA? May be a different technology would do the trick?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  I can understand why you'd want to load a web page into .hta to get a "standalone" website, but the other way around?  I don't see why anyone would even think to want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

HTA is consider by Microsoft as an application (stand alone). Since Microsoft consider the HTA as an application you have more right on the computer such as reading files ( [Full doc on FSO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tkce7xa%28VS.85%29.aspx)), manipulating Excel document ( [Full doc on Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/6958xykx(VS.80).aspx)).

If you could embed a HTA in a web page it would be read only by windows user and would be a security issue on many front.

I have not seen a HTA application embedded in a web page before. I am not saying that it is a definitive no, but I would say that I think that it might be highly improbable.